# SpriteKit scaling for Universal devices

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

After viewing many posts and tutorials on how to support universal devices and properly scale everything so it looks proportional to the device, I am still having trouble. I want my game to look best for iPhone and I understand that setting my scene size using `GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1334, height: 750))` and use `.aspectFill` means that on iPads there will be less space to display things which I'm fine with. The problem is, how do I position my nodes so that they are relative to the each devices frame height and width? I use `self.frame.height`, `self.frame.width`, `self.frame.midX`, etc. for positioning my nodes and when I run my game, it positions things properly considering I run on my iPhone 6, but on my iPad, they're off the screen. I'm having a really hard time understanding all of this scaling, it's giving me a real headache.

Also, I don't really understand the @2x, @3x, of scaling images. I originally just had one size for everything, and when I learned that I needed different size images, I added a couple @2x images to see what happened and my scene looks exactly the same.

Comment: Not sure about SpriteKit stuff, but the @ 2x, @ 3x resolution images are for displaying on screens with different resolutions. e.g. on iPad @ 3x images will be used which will make your sprites sharper. IIRC Xcode also supports vector images now, so you can just use one image and Xcode can generate images with all of the different scalings.

Comment: @DevinLehmacher Oh interesting, so @ 2x and @ 3x aren't needed anymore?

Comment: Yeah, you try to follow the advice given by [this tutorial](https://icons8.com/articles/how-to-use-vectors-in-xcode-7/). You might need to change some stuff for Xcode 8 but I can't find a more recent tutorial.